# What is the Difference Between Algebra and Propositional Calculus/Logic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, propositional-calculus

Hello fellow fans of love! I am attempting to create an understanding of algebra, so I am prepared when I continue my education.

Background:
When I was last in school, I failed the entrance exam (twice) for algebra. I took the alternative Logic instead. My dean urged me to take the prerequisite because Logic was generally considered harder than College Algebra. I was surprised when the questions in Logic came naturally to me and I got 100% with ease. Over 10 years later I was diagnosed (late) with ADHD.

Are algebra and propositional calculus both considered symbolic logic and what are the differences between how these two are logically processed?

Comment: They overlap in [Boolean algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Thx, that makes a lot of sense. Algebra covers multiple areas of mathematical processing, whereas propositional calculus/logic is generally Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Algebra is not usually considered symbolic logic. Logic is a different area of mathematics to algebra (though also an area of philosophy and computer science).

Comment: Which is why I probably love philosophy and computer science!